# Is the physical copy of Battleborn significantly different from the version Steam sells?

Tags: steam, physical-media, battleborn

A local store near me sells Battleborn for a fraction of the price it sells for on Steam. However, this is a physical copy using a disk, and the cover makes it seem like it's only a limited version, since it's talking about free characters and the like. I'm also only interested in the singleplayer, and if this version would be a multiplayer only version, it would be disappointing.

Is the physical copy of Battleborn significantly different from the Steam digital download version?

Comment: Can you give any more information on this "limited edition" copy? Doing a quick google search it seems most stores have Battleborn anywhere from $24.99 - 39.99 as opposed to $59.99 on Steam. It might also have been a used copy, or it is just the DLC (season pass) version?

Comment: @VanBuzzKill with limited edition, I mean limited in features, like a trial or a demo version. Anyway, I bought it and it doesn't seem to be limited in features. The "free characters" it mentioned was just because it was a day one edition they couldn't get rid off.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Battleborn has been shut down as of January 31, 2021

Comment: Voting to leave open per [What do we do with questions about games that can no longer be played?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5565/185203)

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Thank you for letting me know. I have retracted my close vote.